# Problems with elasticsearch:1.7.5 docker image on m1 processor (Macbook pro m1)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, apple-m1

I have a `docker-compose` with some dependencies and elasticsearch (an old version):

Part of my `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: my_web_app-el
    image: elasticsearch:1.7.5
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    expose:
      - "9200"
```

I'm trying to start these images from a Macbook pro with an M1 processor, and I know the architecture arm64 has some issues with docker (like elasticsearch in old versions)
All the containers are up ok, but elasticsearch has a problem:

```
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc

runtime stack:

runtime.throw(0x524da0, 0x9)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90
runtime.newosproc(0xc820028000, 0xc820037fc0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:150 +0x1ab
runtime.newm(0x555ce8, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1105 +0x130
runtime.main.func1()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:48 +0x2c
runtime.systemstack(0x5c4300)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:262 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:674

goroutine 1 [running]:

runtime.systemstack_switch()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:216 fp=0xc820022770 sp=0xc820022768
runtime.main()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:49 +0x62 fp=0xc8200227c0 sp=0xc820022770
runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc8200227c8 sp=0xc8200227c0
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc


runtime stack:

runtime.throw(0x524da0, 0x9)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90
runtime.newosproc(0xc820028000, 0xc820037fc0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:150 +0x1ab
runtime.newm(0x555ce8, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1105 +0x130
runtime.main.func1()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:48 +0x2c
runtime.systemstack(0x5c4300)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:262 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:674


goroutine 1 [running]:

runtime.systemstack_switch()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:216 fp=0xc820022770 sp=0xc820022768
runtime.main()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:49 +0x62 fp=0xc8200227c0 sp=0xc820022770
runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc8200227c8 sp=0xc8200227c0
```

> Important: Other people from my team (without M1 processors) don't have problems with
> this `docker-compose`.

- **I always run `docker-compose up -d --build` with `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` to avoid other problems with architecture.**

I try some approaches to resolve this, like updating the version of elasticsearch, or using alternatives like **webhippie/elasticsearch/** to see what I can do to up my dev environment without any problems.

Is anyone already experiencing this issue with older versions of elasticsearch?

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to come up with some "workarounds" to avoid the elastic-search container problem when I run automated tests on my machine, but the problem persists.

Comment: @LeandroNishijima did you find solution for this please can you share??

Comment: Was having totally the same issue, but couldn't find a way to start it. So just bought non m1 mac :(